# Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered when try to run in iOS by Expo

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

have two weeks that im trying to fix a bug with Expo when i try to run the project witch the cl: `expo start`. In Android, everything is working, but especifically in iOS i got this message error:
`Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't
  called.
  at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:null in error
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleErrorat node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
  at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in 
  at node_modules@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
  at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info.
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:null in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleErrorat node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in 
at node_modules@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://172.25.0.153:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global code`

My package.json:
`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/nunito": "^0.2.2",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
    "expo": "^46.0.13",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-localization": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "^4.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "i18next": "^21.9.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moti": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.33.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-error-boundary": "^1.1.16",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-portalize": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-sound-player": "^0.13.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.18.7",
    "responsive-native": "^1.0.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "zustand": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.69.3",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.12",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

`

metro.config.js:
`

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

  const { transformer, resolver } = config;

  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
  };
  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"],
  };

  return config;
})();
```

`babel.config.js:`

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ['./src'],
          extensions: [
            '.ts',
            '.tsx',
            '.jsx',
            '.js',
            '.json',
            '.svg'
          ],
          alias: {
            '@components': './src/components',
            '@configs': './src/config',
            '@assets': './src/assets',
            '@helpers': './src/helpers',
            '@utils': './src/utils',
            '@types': './src/types',
            '@http': './src/http',
            '@hooks': './src/hooks',
            '@contexts': './src/contexts',
            '@screens': './src/screens',
            '@validators': './src/validators',
            '@stores': './src/stores',
            '@mocks': './src/mocks',
          },
        },
      ],
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
};
```

`

I tryed a lot of things and every help posted here in other asks and github issues too. I tryed to build in Xcode and i got this errors:

`ExpoModulesCore -> Uncategorized -> Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code` and
`FBReactNativeSpec -> Uncategorized -> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed a with nonzero exit code`

I dont know what more i can do to find the error source, i hope that was a library config only and i will be very greatful with every help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my android emulator, try doing something similar with the iOS simululator.

I discovered that my old app was installed in my android emulator.  This fixed it for me:

1. I uninstalled both the app and the new app from the emulator.
2. I killed both Metro and the emulator.
3. I restarted both Metro and the emulator.

It turns out the emulator retains each app it installs instead of starting out as a blank slate each time as I expected. When it starts up, it tries to load the app with the earliest install time. So, it kept trying to run my old app and contact the old Metro server instead of running my new app.